# Is there any tutorial or more specific explaination about the DistanceSensor of Webots

Tags: webots

I was not sure about how to use the different types of DistanceSensors, and how does the gaussianwidth influence the sensor, and about the given 4 distancesensors, how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to one specific robot model?

Here is the main documentation about distance sensors in Webots: https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/distancesensor

You will also find some more information about the distance-sensors of the e-puck for example here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cyberbotics%27_Robot_Curriculum/Novice_programming_Exercises#The_IR_Sensors_[Novice]